# Formatting a &macro variable date in SAS E-Guide

Tags: date, sas, enterprise-guide

The point of the following code is to assign the date of the previous week's Sunday and the date of the previous week's Saturday to a macro variable. I need them in **date9.** format.

In the data step on line 48, I'm formatting them to **date9.**, but they're losing that formatting when called outside of the data step. They're just showing up as the default SAS date format.

What am I missing here?

```
44         data _null_;
45             curDate= today();
46             sunday = intnx('week1.1',curDate,-1,'Begin');
47             saturday = intnx('week1.1',curDate,-1,'End');
48             format _all_ date9.;
49             put (_all_)(=/);
50          call symput('sunday',sunday);
51          call symput('saturday',saturday);
52          
53         run;

NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given     by: (Line):(Column).
      50:23   51:25   

curDate=23JUN2016
sunday=12JUN2016
saturday=18JUN2016
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


54          %PUT &sunday;
20617
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PUT to apply the format directly. You may find that its easier to work with the actual date value in future queries, if you're working with date9 formatted make sure to quote and use the d after when resolving the variable.

I also recommend using call symputX instead.

```
call symputx('sunday',put(sunday, date9.));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation which can become quite annoying... I wrote a macro routine that allows assigning formatted (or unformatted) dates to macro variables, using the sas format of our choosing.

Using the `%letdate` macro, you'd simply do like this:

```
%letdate(sunday, intnx('week1.1',today(),-1,'Begin'), date9.)
%letdate(saturday, intnx('week1.1',today(),-1,'End'), date9.)
```

Log shows:

```
*** Variable macro sunday = 12JUN2016 *** 
*** Variable macro saturday = 18JUN2016 ***
```

The [source code for the macro can be found here](https://gist.github.com/dcomtois/3589a46c7328b9693ddfe2da0db22332); it's documented in French but should be straightforward enough. Just note that:

1. Parameter 1 is the macro variable's name
2. Parameter 2 is the value (as you would write it in a data step)
3. Parameter 3 is the sas format you want to apply to the value of Parameter 2.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Reeza's answer (different code), you can wrap the put function within %sysfunc to output your macro date variable in the format you desire;

```
%put %sysfunc(PutN(&sunday, date9));
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp6IJ.png)

Comment: While this will output the desired formatted date to the log, it doesn't actually meet the requirement of assigning the date to the macro variable in date9. format.